# Accidently vs accidentally

Tags: orthography

Is the form 'accidently' a correct adverb alternative to 'accidentally'?

My kid got this as a spelling exercise and I never encountered the "short" form before. Is this a British thing?

Comment: Hello, Cristi. If you look this up in a dictionary and find conflicting views, it becomes a reasonable topic for ELU. But ELU expects people to do basic research before posting. Try Collins.

Comment: We didn't close [the same question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/21372/accidentally-is-accidently-also-acceptable) on English Language Learners.

Comment: In general (there are exceptions), the adverb is formed from the adjective by adding "ly".  "Accidently" would be the adverb form of "accident", but "accident" is only rarely used as an adjective.

Comment: Sounds like an illiterate school teacher, or at least one obsessed with trivia. Why are your children being given spelling tests? Do you live in Scotland? I could never spell at school and avoided the spelling question in my GCE English because I had learned to write English instead. (Got 95%.) Finally I was justified when computers with spelling checkers came along. Just a rant. No I don't think it is either correct or a British thing.

Comment: I did do basic research and found some occurrences of 'accidently' (e.g. http://www.dictionary.com/browse/accidently - scroll down a bit, both versions of the adverb show up) but I thought mentioning this might influence the answers.

Answer (score 1):

*Accidently* is a common misspelling of *accidentally*.

The adverb *accidentally* comes from the adjective *accidental*.

Washington State University suggests a great way of remembering this:<sup>[1](https://brians.wsu.edu/2016/05/16/accidently/)</sup>

> You can remember this one by remembering how to spell “accidental.” There are quite a few words with -ally suffixes (like “incidentally”) which are not to be confused with words that have “-ly” suffixes (like “independently”). “Incidental” is a word, but “independental” is not.